# Jquery submit is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting two problems in my jquery code. I could not understand the cause for it.

1.I am calling f1() twice- one inside the 'submit' eventhandler and second one, outside the handler. If I remove the f1() call that lies outside the handler, I could see that event handler doesn't get triggered when I click the submit button. (ie. no alert popups)

2.I am always seeing that my ctypes.length is 0 when ever the alert popups. I thought, it has to be the number of fields in the form which is 4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://nvd3.org/assets/css/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script>
function f1(){
ctypes = $("form.chart-series input:checkbox");
alert(ctypes.length);
}

f1();
$('.chart-series').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    f1()
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form class="chart-series">
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chart_name" value="1" checked/> a</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chart_name" value="2" checked/> b</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chart_name" value="3" /> c</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chart_name" value="4" /> d</li>

<input type="submit" class="btn chart-submit" value="update"/>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Your script code does get executed before the form element even exists – so of course you get a length of 0, because no elements were matched, and you also did not attach a submit handler to anything.

Comment: As CBroe said run your code after DOM is ready($(document).ready(function{}()))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert scripts at bottom of the page and wrap your code in $(document).ready();

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://nvd3.org/assets/css/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form class="chart-series">
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chart_name" value="1" checked/> a</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chart_name" value="2" checked/> b</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chart_name" value="3" /> c</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chart_name" value="4" /> d</li>

<input type="submit" class="btn chart-submit" value="update"/>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
function f1(){
ctypes = $("form.chart-series input:checkbox");
alert(ctypes.length);
}

f1();
$('.chart-series').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    f1()
});
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in `$(document).ready()`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function f1(){
        ctypes = $("form.chart-series input:checkbox");
        alert(ctypes.length);
    }

    f1();
    $('.chart-series').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        f1();
    });
});
```